# Transit 6 hours with passport validity less than 2 months

Tags: passports, singapore, sri-lankan-citizens, maldives

I am prepared to fly to Maldives from Bali next week and the major issue for me is my passport validity is less than 2 months. The tour package is already booked and not refundable. I have two options either take the risk and travel or skip the plan and forget about the money.

Itinerary is from Singapore airlines and the transit from Singapore to Male. Assuming they allow me to board the flight will I face any issue at the Singapore airport during my 6 hour transit?

And will the  Maldives Immigration deport me due to validity of my passport expires less than 2 months? I am a Sri Lankan citizen.

Comment: Are you a Bali citizen?

Comment: I am a citizen of Srilanka and my return flight back to home just after 7 days in Maldives

Answer (score 4):

I agree that the Maldives will refuse you entry.

If an airline carries a passenger who is refused entry at a destination or a transit location, the airline is required to return that passenger to the point of departure *at the airline's expense* (although the airline may later try to recoup the cost from the passenger).

Thus, airlines are very careful to check passenger's documents to make sure the passenger will be accepted. Before allowing a passenger to board a flight, the carrier will check passenger documents against the requirements shown in [Timatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic), a database of the required documents for specific flights and transits.

Thus, you won't actually get to the Maldives: your documents will be checked in Bali, your passport will be found insufficient (because it expires too soon), and you will be refused boarding onto the Bali > Maldives flight.

Daniil's advice is correct.

Answer (score 3):

All nationalities need at least 6 months on their passport for a visa:

> 1. Should posses a valid passport with Machine Readable Zone (MRZ) -(standard ICAO Annex 9, chapter 3.10.1)and should have at least 6 months validity

([Maldive Embassy Website](https://maldivesembassy.uk/index.php/maldives/maldives-visa-and-passport-information))

You would probably be refused entry. Singaporean authorities don’t check your passport on transit.

Either:

- You renew your passport urgently in time for your trip
- You don’t go on the trip